# File Browse for Uploading Attachments inside and On Demand Process

Tags: jquery-ui, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle ApEx 3.0.1 and I was wondering if the "File browse" item type for upload attachments into Oracle ApEx 3.0.1 via an On Demand Process works when calling using ajax call to an on demand process and passing in relevant information.

For the attachment to to added to apex_application_files, does the page need to be submitted as I have my file browse process inside a jQuery dialog box?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

My on demand process code is:

```
BEGIN
  IF ( :AI_FILENAME is not null ) then 
      insert into request_attachments 
                          ( request_id,
                            doc_reference,
                            name,
                            description,
                            contents, 
                            mime_type ) 
      select 100,
             :AI_DOC_REFERENCE,
             substr(:AI_FILENAME, instr(:AI_FILENAME, '/')+1),
             :AI_DESCRIPTION,
             blob_content,
             mime_type
      from   apex_application_files where name = :AI_FILENAME;

      delete from wwv_flow_files where name = :AI_FILENAME;
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but there are some potential solutions given [here on the Oracle Apex forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9463276�).